# getting assigned variables when exception is raised, python exception handeling

Tags: python, exception

I would like to find a way to get the variables I assigned before an exception is made. E.G if the code is

```
try:
  a=b
  c=d
  e=f
except:
  bla bla
```

And an exception is generated at "e=f," I still want a=b and c=d

Is it possible? I realize I could make this multiple try statements but is there something I can do in one step?

Comment: An exception is only raised where the code breaks. You can't get information of the code before or after it.

Comment: Hello. What do you mean with _"I still want a=b and c=d"_ ?? Be more explanatory please

Comment: a and c should exist if that code ran...

Comment: @ValekHalfHeart, I don't believe they will disappear. I'm telling OP they will exist and there's not a problem to solve in his question

Comment: @user32117386 Hello. Did you read my answer ?

Answer (score 4):

Yes, it is perfectly possible.  Below is a demonstration:

```
>>> try:
...     a = 1
...     b = 2
...     c = 1/0 # This will raise a ZeroDivisionError
... except ZeroDivisionError:
...     print 'an error occurred'
...
an error occurred
>>> a  # a still exists
1
>>> b  # so does b
2
>>> c  # only c is undefined
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in <module>
NameError: name 'c' is not defined
>>>
```

[`try/except`](http://docs.python.org/2/reference/compound_stmts.html#the-try-statement) is designed to execute the code in the try-block normally until an exception is raised.  When that happens, the try-block is immediately exited.  This means that only the code *after* the line that raised the exception is ignored.

Comment: But this has no practical value, since you're not gonna know where the exception was raised. If you are trying to catch exceptions from all 3 expressions, and you want to know where it was raised, you need to use 3 try...except blocks.

Comment: Also if C had an initial value before `try`, that value would be kept. So this has practical value to check the variable sanity.

Answer (score 1):

The best you can do is to limit the number of expressions inside your `try` block.

If you **need** to know where the exception is raised, you are probably better off using multiple `try...except`'s like you mentioned in your queestion, since there is no (practical) way to know where the exception was raised.

If the expressions are of the same type, you may want to put them in lists though, and loop over them, like:

```
vars = [a, b, c]
values = [1, 2, 0]

for i, (var, value) in enumerate(zip(vars, values)):
    try:
        var /= value
    except ZeroDivisionError:
        print 'The exception was raised on the {}. iteration'.format(i)
        continue
```

Answer (score 0):

```
try:
  a = "foo"
  c = "bar"
  e = unknown_function()
except:
  pass

print a, c # prints "foo bar"
```

Both `a` and `c` are set, you can simply use their values after the exception is handled. `e` is not set to anything as an exception was raised when that line was executed.

Answer (score 0):

If I understand you correctly, this will happen by default. Raising an exception does not magically undo everything that has already happened inside the try block. In your example, if an error occurs on the assignment of `e`, `a` and `c` will still have the values they were assigned.

```
try:
    a = b
    c = d
    e = f # oh noes! error! Try block skips to the end!
except: pass

print (a) #but a and c are still there
print (c)
```

Answer (score 0):

This is a straight forward method without much of a hassle . This is the best way out when you cant predict what type of error can occur, or multiple errors can occur .

```
try :
    a=10
except :
    print "bla A"
try :
    b=20
except:
    print "bla B"
try:
    c=d
except :
    print "bla C"
```

Answer (score 0):

Is it something like this that  you want ?

```
import sys

code = """
b = 100
d = 200

a=b
c=d
e=10/0
g=e
h = 100
"""

for line in filter(None,code.splitlines()):
    print line
    try:
        exec line
    except:
        sys.excepthook(sys.exc_info()[0],sys.exc_info()[1],None)
```

result

```
b = 100
d = 200
a=b
c=d
e=10/0
ZeroDivisionError: integer division or modulo by zero
g=e
NameError: name 'e' is not defined
h = 100
```